# How can I use Windows' built-in OpenSSH ssh-agent in VS Code, instead of Git bash's?

Tags: windows, git, ssh, visual-studio-code, git-for-windows

I am running OpenSSH on Windows, using the [built-in OpenSSH included since the Autumn/Fall Creators Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview).

I am using ssh just fine in my PowerShell, but Visual Studio Remote Development (and I guess Git for Windows?) are not using my OpenSSH. Instead, they seem to be using the Git for Windows SSH client from MinGW. This means all my `ssh-add`ed keys are not present in the VS or Git `ssh-agent`.

**How can I get Visual Studio (and maybe Git?) to use the builtin OpenSSH install so that I can use the same `ssh-agent` between them all?**

### PowerShell

Here is what SSH looks like in PowerShell:

```
c:\Users\myusername
> Get-Command ssh

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     ssh.exe                                            7.7.2.1    C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe

c:\Users\myusername
> Get-Command ssh-agent

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     ssh-agent.exe                                      7.7.2.1    C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-agent.exe

C:\Users\myusername
> Get-Command ssh-add

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     ssh-add.exe                                        7.7.2.1    C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-add.exe

c:\Users\myusername
> ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:HASH_HERE C:\Users\myusername\.ssh\id_rsa (RSA)
```

### Git Bash

```bash
myusername@COMPUTERNAME MINGW64 ~
$ which ssh
/usr/bin/ssh

myusername@COMPUTERNAME MINGW64 ~
$ which ssh-agent
/usr/bin/ssh-agent

myusername@COMPUTERNAME MINGW64 ~
$ which ssh-add
/usr/bin/ssh-add

myusername@COMPUTERNAME MINGW64 ~
$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

### Visual Studio

I am using [VS Code Remote Development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview). Every time I log in to my remote computer, I am prompted for my private key's password.

Without private key auth, I am prompted for my logon password (for the remote user).

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [known issue/regression](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2522) with VS Code Remote Development.

The workaround is simple: change VS Code's SSH path.

1. Open VS Code settings.
2. Search for `remote.SSH.path`.
3. Change the setting to `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe` (or `C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe` if editing JSON).

VS Code will now use the OpenSSH `ssh-agent`.

Comment: When I tried to search for such setting, it dedicated No Settings Found

Comment: Thanks! This allowed vscode to use my agent :)

Answer (score 2):

For me creating a system environment variable (user environment varibale should do too) `GIT_SSH=C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe` allowed me to use Windows 10 OpenSSH Agent with VS Code.