# VS Code SSH keeps dropping connections, but I can SSH just fine

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I set up SSH on a remote machine & a local machine, with the intent of using [VS Code SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh). I can connect to my remote with `ssh` in the command line, but VS Code keeps dropping connections *after successfully connecting* with something like `ssh child died, shutting down`.

Why can I connect via CLI SSH, but not VS Code? How do I fix this?

### Background

- Setup

  - Followed the instructions on [Get started with OpenSSH for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=powershell) and [Key-based authentication in OpenSSH for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement) to set up initial SSH.
- Validation

  - `ssh -l REDACTED\citelao citelao-machine -vvv` works just fine
  - I confirmed I'm using the OpenSSH `ssh-agent` ([How can I use Windows' built-in OpenSSH ssh-agent in VS Code, instead of Git bash's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819352/how-can-i-use-windows-built-in-openssh-ssh-agent-in-vs-code-instead-of-git-bas/60821774#60821774))
  - I turned on super-verbose logs on the server, but couldn't find anything suspicious ([Starting OpenSSH server in Windows with debug messages enabled (-d)](https://superuser.com/questions/1635361/starting-openssh-server-in-windows-with-debug-messages-enabled-d#:%7E:text=The%20Windows%20OpenSSH%20server%20logs%20to%20the%20event,OpenSSH%20logging%20is%20controlled%20by%20your%20C%3AProgramDatasshsshd_config%20file))
  - I tried increasing `ServerAliveInterval 60` and `ServerAliveCountMax 30`
  - I tried `PubkeyAuthentication no` and `PasswordAuthentication yes` (and tried with pubkey authentication)

How do I fix this, so I can connect in VS Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Disable **Remote.SSH: Use Local Server** (set `remote.SSH.useLocalServer` to `false`):

[image: Use Local Server]

Per Rob Lourens in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6521):

> You are hitting a bug with some versions of the windows ssh server :/

### More information

Relevant logs from the issue (I couldn't get my own logs after fixing the issue):

```
[16:11:07.635] stderr> Authenticated to 127.0.0.1 ([127.0.0.1]:22).
[16:11:10.183] stderr> client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer
[16:11:10.244] > local-server-1> ssh child died, shutting down
[16:11:10.368] Local server exit: 0

// ...

client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer
local-server-1> ssh child died, shutting down

[16:11:10.370] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[16:11:10.374] Resolver error: Error: 
    at Function.Create (c:\Users\alros\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.79.2022040715\out\extension.js:1:585789)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\alros\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.79.2022040715\out\extension.js:1:584441)
    at Object.e [as tryInstallWithLocalServer] (c:\Users\alros\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.79.2022040715\out\extension.js:1:624908)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async c:\Users\alros\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.79.2022040715\out\extension.js:1:643945
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\alros\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.79.2022040715\out\extension.js:1:647692)
    at async c:\Users\alros\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.79.2022040715\out\extension.js:1:623380
    at async b (c:\Users\alros\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.79.2022040715\out\extension.js:1:619886)
    at async Object.t.resolveWithLocalServer (c:\Users\alros\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.79.2022040715\out\extension.js:1:622995)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\alros\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.79.2022040715\out\extension.js:1:645302)
    at async c:\Users\alros\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.79.2022040715\out\extension.js:1:722235
[16:11:10.380] ------
```